# Exception has occurred: AttributeError: __exit__

Tags: python

I am trying to use **[DeepRF/data_synthetic.py](https://github.com/thijor/DeepRF/blob/main/data_synthetic.py)** script. Below is my code to use the `Noise` class defined in the [data_synthetic.py](https://github.com/thijor/DeepRF/blob/main/data_synthetic.py) script:

**MWE:**

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import os

# DeepRF module
deeprf_module_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../DeepRF-main'))
sys.path.append(deeprf_module_path)
from data_synthetic import *
import data_synthetic as deeprf_data_synthetic

# testing DeepRF
TR = 1.2 # seconds
low_frequency_noise = deeprf_data_synthetic.LowFrequency(0.9, TR )
physiological_noise = deeprf_data_synthetic.Physiological(0.9, TR)
system_noise = deeprf_data_synthetic.System(0.9, np.random.RandomState)
task_noise = deeprf_data_synthetic.Task(0.9, np.random.RandomState)
temporal_noise = deeprf_data_synthetic.Temporal(0.9, np.random.RandomState)

test_t = np.arange(0, 300, 1)
test_signal = np.ones_like(test_t)

# Create a Noise instance with specified noise components and amplitudes
random_generator_t = np.random.RandomState(64556) # used to generate random parameters
random_generator_x = np.random.RandomState(23355) # used to generate random signal/noise
random_generator_y = np.random.RandomState(1258566) # used to generate predictions
noise = deeprf_data_synthetic.Noise(random_generator_y.rand(5), low_frequency_noise, physiological_noise, system_noise, task_noise, temporal_noise)

# Create a synthetic fMRI time series (replace this with your actual data)
fmri_data = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=300)

# Apply the noise to the fMRI data using the __call__ method
noisy_fmri_data = noise(fmri_data)
```

**PROBLEM:** The execution of the last line of my code `noisy_fmri_data = noise(fmri_data)` leads to the execution of line-144 of the [data_synthetic.py](https://github.com/thijor/DeepRF/blob/main/data_synthetic.py) script, which is throwing an exception (screenshot below):

> Exception has occurred: AttributeError: **exit**

[image]

Comment: In `system_noise = deeprf_data_synthetic.System(0.9, np.random.RandomState)`, you pass the class object `np.random.RandomState`. Should it instead be an instance of the class (such as `np.random.RandomState()`) ? The same issue on the following two lines.

Comment: @slothrop: Correct! ChatGPT proposed a similar solution but it did not work. By making your suggested change, I am now getting the exception `'float' object has no attribute 'astype'` on the same line.

Comment: Right, I see. My guess is that this is a bug in your version of the library. What is probably intended on line 144 is `self.random_generator.normal(0, sigma, n)` - i.e. an array of *n* samples of a normal distribution centred on 0 with width *sigma*. But instead there is `self.random_generator.normal(sigma, n)` - that returns a single float drawn from a distribution centred on *sigma* with width *n*. That (a) seems odd and (b) gives the error you see, because `.astype` is a method of numpy arrays, not of floats.

Comment: The bug seems to be fixed in the latest version: https://github.com/thijor/DeepRF/blob/7f07c2d399b3f6969826e4f5506b00262de4f16c/data_synthetic.py#L143 has `self.random_generator.normal(scale=sigma, size=n).astype('float32')` which is fine because the params are specified by keyword. So make sure you get the latest version of the library, and this issue should be resolved.

Comment: @slothrop: Thanks a lot. It worked! Please create an answer, will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question passes the class object `np.random.RandomState` to the constructors of `System`, `Task` and `Temporal`, whereas what is needed is an instance object. So these lines:

```
system_noise = deeprf_data_synthetic.System(0.9, np.random.RandomState)
task_noise = deeprf_data_synthetic.Task(0.9, np.random.RandomState)
temporal_noise = deeprf_data_synthetic.Temporal(0.9, np.random.RandomState)
```

should become:

```
system_noise = deeprf_data_synthetic.System(0.9, np.random.RandomState())
task_noise = deeprf_data_synthetic.Task(0.9, np.random.RandomState())
temporal_noise = deeprf_data_synthetic.Temporal(0.9, np.random.RandomState())
```

From the comments, it also seems you had an outdated version of the `DeepRF` library and encountered some further errors: but these weren't reproducible with the latest version on Github. So if you make the changes above, and ensure you have the latest version of the library, your problem should be resolved.